# Execute effect specified by string

Tags: jquery, effects

I am currently trying to execute effects with jQuery. However, I do not want want to do anything like `$("#something").hide()`, I would like to specify the effect in a string. Here is an example:

```
var selector = "#myElement";
var effectString = "hide";
$(selector).effect(effectString);
```

I looked this code up, and apparently it did work that way, but for some reason the `effect()` method seems to have been removed.

My question is if there is any alternative that I could use. Or has a feature like this been intentionally removed? I am using jquery-3.2.1.

Thanks in advance for any helping thoughts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the response to a selector is an object, you can use bracket notation to access the method names using a variable and invoke them, like this:

```js
var selector = "#myElement";
var effectString = "hide";
$(selector)[effectString]();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  Part of this <span id="myElement">string</span> will be hidden
</div>
```